# Laravel | ReflectionException - Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, package, composer-php

I created a package in the Laravel 4 workbench and it worked like a charm on my machine. Everything loaded as expected but now on another machine I'm getting the Class not found exception.

What I have:

composer.json (root)

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "workbench"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Please note that the workbench directory is listed.

Inside the workbench directory I have the vendor and package folders:
workbench/krynble/contenter

Inside is the regular package structure but the most important is that there is another composer.json file (created when the package was generated):

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/migrations"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Krynble\\Contenter\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

So inside of it I followed the steps to create the Service Provider cited in the documentation

workbench/krynble/contenter/src/Krynble/Contenter/ContenterSerivceProvider.php (also generated automaticaly) and left it as created, with only the boot method as follows:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->package('krynble/contenter');
}
```

register:

```
public function register()
{
    //
}
```

provides:

```
public function provides()
{
    return array();
}
```

Added this service provider to my app.php in the providers list and invoking a die() in the boot function shows it's being called.

Last, I created my utility class:

workbench/krynble/contenter/src/Krynble/Contenter/Services/Mappers/MediaMapperSerivce.php

```
<?

namespace Krynble\Contenter\Services\Mappers;
class MediaMapperService {
...
}
```

Finally, in my controller:

```
<?php

use Krynble\Contenter\Services\Mappers\MediaMapperService;

class MediaController extends BaseController {

    private $mediaMapperService;


    public function __construct(MediaMapperService $mediaMapperService)
    {
        $this->mediaMapperService = $mediaMapperService;
    }
```

Nice! It worked on my machine (vagrant box with ubuntu)! But on the mac notebook it's not working (so I discarded the case-sensitive thing).

Any clues? Any way to debug? I'm going nuts, thrown die() in every point and can't seem to find the source.

Am I supposed to add something in the provides method in my service provider? If so, why did it work on my machine without adding this?

Comment: Does `composer dump-autoload` help?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not. It runs and shows me Running for workbench [krynble/contenter]... but nothing changes =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a log of digging, I found out the problem was the weirdest of all: the short_open_tag setting in local computer was set to 1 and was set to 0 in my QA environment.

The file wasn't being parsed (but no error raised) and I was getting the class does not exist message.